# Google Play Referral Flow remains empty

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play

As shown here http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2013/10/improved-app-insight-by-linking-google.html we can now link our playstore apps to analytics and see the Google Play Referral Flow

I linked one of our apps to an Analytics account/property. Still Google Play Referral Flow remains empty even after 2 days of waiting. The App has Google Analytics integrated. Any what could be wrong or missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found that Google Play Referral Flow only displays analytics for visitors coming via a referral source in the link to Google Play. Organic searches and clicks without a referral source in the URL do not show up at all.

Comment: how can we identify which keywords and search terms are directed to our app page in playstore and how many visits has our app page received in playstore