# Analytics Google Play Referral Flow

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play, settings

Last week I enabled "Get Google Play Developer Console Data" property in the Google Analytics account.

But it seems to be a problem with the Google Play -> Referral Flow report. Although in Google Play console there are hundreds of installs reported, in Analytics are only 5.

The installs may be caused by the the [data collection sampling](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192#collection-sampling), but I am pretty sure we have more than 6 views.

Does anyone else face the same problem? Are there additional settings that must be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266860/google-play-referral-flow-remains-empty